# Ionic Input has some odd inner right padding

Tags: html, css, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have the following code:

```
<div class="row no-padding" style="margin-top: 0px;">
    <div class="col-67 no-padding">
       <label class="item item-input">
          <input name="email" ng-model="model.email" placeholder="Email" required type="email">
       </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col no-padding">
       <label class="item item-input">
          <input name="mobile" ng-model="model.number" placeholder="Mobile" required type="tel">
       </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

And I get an input boxes with odd inner right padding:
[image]
(Note the .com gets cut off & the number should be 123456789)

Is there a way to reduce this?

I tried using in the input without avail the following:

`<input name="email" style="padding-right: -25px; ng-model="model.email" placeholder="Email" required type="email">`

**Update:** I am using Ionic Framework

Comment: You can't use minus values on padding. Can you create a fiddle so we can see the full CSS?

Comment: please post your css also?because its may be affect by other css ?

Comment: I am using Ionic, the CSS is rather complex to show here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Input item on ionic has a padding of 24px. You can remove that padding in this way

```
.item-input input {
   padding-right: 0;
}
```

Comment: used style="padding-right: 15px;" for the input object, thank you

Comment: Oh ok you reduced the padding. I am glad I helped

Comment: I'm curious as to why it's there in the 1st place